# CRM_SMS_Page_Callback run method override

Tags: civisms

I am creating a new extension to add a new SMS provider. Since different parameters are passed during callback, I need to override run method of the CRM_SMS_Page_Callback class. Since it is a part of CRM Core, what is the best way to do it?

> sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/SMS/Page/Callback.php

```
class CRM_SMS_Page_Callback {

  public function run() {
    $provider = CRM_SMS_Provider::singleton($_REQUEST);

    if (array_key_exists('status', $_REQUEST)) {
      $provider->callback();
    }
    else {
      $provider->inbound();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say parameters do you mean http get/post parameters? You would just access those in your callback the usual way in php. Or see for example the callback function for clickatell

https://github.com/veda-consulting/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/blob/master/org_civicrm_sms_clickatell.php

Comment: Yes, I mean GET parameters. My SMS provider does not use 'status' parameter necessary for the callback() method to fire.

Comment: Then in your inbound() function you could also branch and call callback() as necessary.